# Angular input validation for Emoji

Tags: angular, emoji, angular-validation

How to validate input for Emoji. If input Emoji need to show error message.

Form field is

```
 'name': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: we used prime ng and angualr 4

Comment: need the name of Emoji plugin

Comment: You can add validation of what you will allow , automatically emoji validation will fails in that case

Comment:  example take this . how can i validate this ? the entered input is emoji or not

Comment: https://getemoji.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom validation function and use it in your component file.

I created a common custom function and for that create one component file:

**custom-Validatiors.ts**

```
export function Noemotics(): ValidatorFn {
   return (control: AbstractControl): any => {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
         if (control.value && control.value != '') {
             let trimedvalue = control.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/gm, '');
             control.setValue(trimedvalue);
          }
      }, 10);
   };
}
```

Now you can use this function anywhere in your project. You should have to import this function into a component file.

```
  import { Noemotics } from '../Shared/custom-validators';
```

Specify this function into where you have to give validation to your form controls.
In angular we are using just like below given:

```
    this.RegisterFormGroup = this.fb.group({        
        firstname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Noemotics()])]          
    });
```